# WS_EX_LAYERED window does not receive mouse events

Tags: c++, events, winapi, transparency, ws-ex-layered

I'm coding a custom background non rectangular window with buttons such as minimize and close in bitmaps.
[Here is my code just for now](http://pastie.org/1092728)
The problem is the custom window does not receive mouse messages while hovering over non zero alpha regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since minimize and close buttons are outside window client area, you need to capture WM_NCLBUTTONUP in addition to WM_LBUTTONUP

Comment: I see. Since I'm almost always returning HTCAPTION in WM_NCHITTEST, I need to process non-client mouse messages. But I'm now having problem with WM_NCLBUTTONUP - it's triggered only after double click on the window. Is it OS specific? I have Win XP SP3. I saw a solution for this problem involving SetWindowsHook for mouse messages, but it's rather ugly.

Comment: There is a difference between WM_NCLBUTTONUP and WM_LBUTTONUP. From MSDN

**WM_LBUTTONUP**:
 *If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window beneath the cursor. Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse.*

**WM_NCLBUTTONUP**:
*If a window has captured the mouse, this message is not posted.*